# D3: add filter as background to SVG element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In D3 I'd like to apply a background colour to my axis labels. It could be done with `rect` but using SVG filters looks like a nicer option since they adapt to the size of the labels. I've come [this far (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/speedymcs/uab99gtg/2/) using

```
var filterDef = svg.append("defs");
var filter = filterDef.append("filter")
        .attr("id", "textBackground")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 1)
        .attr("height", 1)
        .append("feFlood")
        .attr("flood-color", "green")
        .attr("result","txtBackground")
var filterMerge = filter.append("feMerge");
filterMerge.append("feMergeNode")
        .attr("in", "txtBackground");
filterMerge.append("feMergeNode")
        .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");            
d3.selectAll(".xAxis>.tick>text")
    .style("filter", "url(#textBackground)");
```

but the filters are added in front of the `text` elements, even though I've closely followed [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5200394).

Comment: Use an feMerge filter to merge the original text element (the SourceGraphic) into the filter output.

Comment: thank you @RobertLongson, I've tried it but I must be missing something. updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there, you just need to get the filter hierarchy right. The filter elements need to be siblings.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var w = 500, h = 200;
var padding = 50;
svg.attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([padding, w-padding]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(5);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","xAxis")
    .call(xAxis);
var filterDef = svg.append("defs");
var filter = filterDef.append("filter")
            .attr("id", "textBackground")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 1)
            .attr("height", 1);
   filter         
            .append("feFlood")
            .attr("flood-color", "green")
            .attr("result","txtBackground")
var filterMerge = filter.append("feMerge");
filterMerge.append("feMergeNode")
            .attr("in", "txtBackground");
filterMerge.append("feMergeNode")
            .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");            
d3.selectAll(".xAxis>.tick>text")
  .style("filter", "url(#textBackground)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So close! Thanks! :)